# After hiding NSRunningApplications some automatically unhide

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsworkspace

Im using the following code to hide all the running applications whose `activationPolicy == .regular` and if the bundle identifier is different from my app.

```
NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications
     .filter { runningApps.contains($0.bundleIdentifier) }
     .forEach { item in
          item.hide()
}
```

Right after hiding them some just automatically unhide, apps that usually have a search bar or first responder textview like telegram, finder, messages. It's random and sometimes it reappears, sometimes not...

I also tried with `NSWorkspace.shared.hideOtherApplications()` but it does the same

macOS 10.14.3

Any idea on what should I do before hiding?

Comment: Is your application the frontmost (active) application? You can't hide all of the apps; the active app will always be visible.

Comment: Well my app is a menu bar app and when it changes the desktop image it shows a popup. The user could have any other app active. I have a button that hides all the active apps and shows them back after 3 seconds. You can hide manually with cmd + h any window so I tough it's the same thing

Comment: A "menu bar" app is typically a background (LSUIElement) app, so it is never the "active" app. Therefore, some other app is always going to be the active app (the one controlling the menubar) and as such, you can't hide it. Yes, you can manually hide an app with Command+H ... but not the last app; when all of the other apps are hidden, the (app) > Hide (app) command is disable. You can also see this after choosing (app) > Hide Others.

Comment: This makes sense

Comment: As a hack, you could (a) change the run mode of your background app to "regular" (so it now appears in the Dock and can become the active app), (b) make your app the active app, (c) then you could hide all of the other apps.

Comment: That should work but instead of hiding all the windows to show the desktop for me worked better to show a window fullscreen over all the windows with the desktop image set. Thanks